# Background image wont load on github pages

Tags: html, css, git, image, github

The photos for the buttons on home screen will load if I open the index file directly however when I upload the page to git hub pages two of the photos wont load properly

link to the files : [github.com/Pyrrhus-Cascello/Pyrrhus-Cascello.github.io](https://github.com/Pyrrhus-Cascello/Pyrrhus-Cascello.github.io)

link to the page  : [cascello.com/](http://cascello.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your github repo again, you'll see that you have two images folders, one in Uppercase (Images) one in lowercase (images). On your page, you always link to /images/, but not all images are stored there.

Edit your image-url for button one and two to point to the right directory:

```
background-image: url('../Images/Money.jpg') no-repeat;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just moved everything back into the one folder and now it works